Self-Organizing maps: why input vectors (x) are dependent on steps (t)?
Based on the paper Essentials of the Self-Organizing maps, I rephrase paragraph 4.1. ->The original, stepwise recursive SOM algorithm:
In the mathematical framework $\{\mathbf{x}(t)\}$ represents the set of the input data vectors at step $t$, while $\{\mathbf{m}_i(t)\}$ is the set of n-dimensional vectors (called nodes) at time $t$ that represents the successively computed approximation of the model (a model represents the entire set of trained nodes for a single iteration) $\mathbf{m}_i$.
The SOM algorithm assumes that the following process has a convergence:
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{m}_i(t+1) = \mathbf{m}_i(t) + h_{c,i}(t)[\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{m}_i(t)],
    \label{eq:steps}
\end{equation}
where $h_{c,i}(t)$ represents the neighborhood function and $c$ is the index of the particular node (called winner) that has the closest distance from $\mathbf{x}(t)$. Formally:
\begin{equation}
    c = argmin_i\{||\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{m}_i(t)||\}.
    \label{eq:winning_node}
\end{equation}
Here I'm wondering why the input vector $\{\mathbf{x}(t)\}$ does need to depend on $t$, isn't it independent from $t$, since it is always the same during the entire process?
Thanks.

I don't have access to the paper, but is it possible that $x(t)$ is the residual error (which would depend on $t$ since we keep on adding )?
